# Order of precedence for NuGet packages that support multiple target frameworks

Tags: .net, nuget-package, .net-standard

I have a NuGet package that supports multiple target frameworks `net45` and `netstandard2.0`.  There are differences in the code for the target frameworks (conditional compilation).

If I reference this package from a .NET Framework 4.6.1 application, it appears to choose the `net45` version over the `netstandard2.0` version, though it is nominally compatible with both.

What are the precedence rules that determine this choice?  Will the choice be the same for applications built for later .NET Frameworks (4.7.2, 4.8, ...)?

Comment: "though it is nominally compatible with both" is not true. There are complex cases it must use `net451`, so package authors rely on such order of precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will pick the highest matching target framework less than or equal to your app's target framework, provided the library has such a target.

If it doesn't, it will fall back to a netstandard target if one exists.

Failing that, the library isn't compatible.

It's a bit frustrating the docs aren't more detailed about this, and they don't cover more complex scenarios (e.g. `net461` app,  referencing `netstandard2.0` libA, in turn referencing multi targeted `netstandard2.0,net461` libB - which framework is resolved for libB?). For those you just have to try it and see.

See docs, such as they are, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting#multi-targeting) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#grouping-assemblies-by-framework-version)